# Why is pressure head ignored in open channel flow?

Tags: hydraulics, open-channel-flow

Also, what does this excerpt from Wikipedia mean

***However, since with open channel flow, the water surface is open to the atmosphere, the pressure term between two points has the same value and is therefore ignored.***

Answer (score 2):

Because head pressure is the weight of the water standing on top of the region being measured. Even though you can visualize an open channel as a slope you will not see a difference in pressure if you measure one foot deep at any point on the slope; this is because you are only measuring the weight of the water above the measuring point.

Comment: Okay. And what are the two points that are considered in the sentence in the question?

Comment: two points along the length of the channel...

Comment: Any 2 points along the open channel. If you look at a 2ft deep sluice that drops 5 ft over a 50 ft run and observe the pressure 1ft down on the bottom at the top it will be the same as 1 ft down at the top. This is because it is only measuring 1 ft of water pushing down on the pressure gauge. If it were a solid filled pipe you would read 1 ft depth at the top and 5 ft at the bottom because the solid run of pipe has the same amount of water pushing down on the gauge as a 5 ft deep tank.